PyCharm will not debug if a test is failing
I have the following test code:
def sums(a,b):
    n = a+b
    return n

def prods(a,b):
    n = a+b
    return n


import unittest

class TestClientes(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_000_sums(self):
        self.assertEqual(sums(1,2),3)
        self.assertEqual(sums(10,2),12)

    def test_001_prods(self):
        self.assertEqual(prods(1,2),2)
        self.assertEqual(prods(10,2),20)

        

def runTests():
        suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(TestClientes)
        unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2,failfast=True).run(suite)

runTests()

This is working as intended in VS Code, using both the run option and the debug option (with the debug option, I can mark the first line of the prods function and I get to run the code step by step as expected).
I cannot, however, convince PyCharm to do the same. When I open the folder as a project (note that I did not create the project in PyCharm, it's just a vanilla folder) and ask the code to be debugged, it just runs the test suite, gives me a failed message, and no step by step code execution.
In fact, I get step-by-step execution of a parse.py file that I did not create.
The way I am debugging the code is by

Opening the folder as a project
Marking the first line of prods as a breakpoint by clicking the line number -- and the line number gets a red dot
Clicking the 'bug' icon in the image below


Is there a way to run the debugger and get step by step execution?
If so, what is the one that involves the least complex configuration (I am using such tests as teaching code, and my students are learning to program, so simplicity of procedure is paramount).

Works fine in PyCharm for me. FYI you could just do if __name__ == "__main__": unittest.main(verbosity=2, failfast=True), which would also allow that functionality to be imported without testing it.
